# Displaying Categories in Ascending Order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, controller

I am building a dropdown menu that displays categories in Ruby on Rails and would like to display the dropdown in alphabetical order (A...Z).

Question:
***"Can I order the dropdown menu alphabetically via editing the methods in the controller or views?"***

Since they are not alphabetically seeded in the database, I was wondering if there was a way to have data display data that currently looks like this by default:

|*DROPDOWN*|
|_Cooking____|
|_Zoology____|
|_History_____|
|_Gardening__|
|_Archery____|

into:

|DROPDOWN|
|_Archery____|
|_Cooking____|
|_Gardening__|
|_History_____|
|_Zoology____|

Currently, Categories has values *id, name, created_at, and updated_at*.

Here is a snippet of the database's ActiveRecord relation:

ActiveRecord::Relation
Category id: 1, name: "Technology", created_at: "2017-10-10 21:48:59", updated_at: "2017-10-10 21:48:59"
 
Category id: 2, name: "Horror/Mystery", created_at: "2017-10-10 21:50:38", updated_at: "2017-10-11 00:06:38"
 
Category id: 3, name: "Fantasy", created_at: "2017-10-10 21:50:43", updated_at: "2017-10-10 21:50:43"
Category id: 4, name: "Historical Fiction", created_at: "2017-10-10 21:50:51", updated_at: "2017-10-10 21:50:51"

If this is not sufficient, I can provide the relevant files to help shed light on the issue.

Thank you for taking time out of your day to give me a hand!

Answer (score 1):

If your category is associated with a resource and you are trying to display all the categories in a form that needs to be saved.I am assuming that you have a resource like articles and wants to add a category to the article while saving into the database.

```
    def new
    @article = Article.new
    @temp = Category.alphabetically
    @categories = @temp.all.map{|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }
    end
```

in your categories model

category.rb

```
 class Category < ApplicationRecord
    scope :alphabetically, -> { order(name: :asc) }
 end
```

In the view

_form.html.erb

```
 <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), class: "form-control", :prompt => "Select one!") %>
```

Please let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, here is the sample (consider you using form_for with f as form variable)

```
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.uniq.pluck(:name, :id).sort, { include_blank: true }, { class: 'your class name' } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call all categories in ascending order based on your attribute name

@categories = Categories.all(:order => "name ASC")

here "name Asc" name refers to category name

try this in rails console ..You can see that order